# Bibtex: I didn't find a database entry for "Citation"

Tags: bibtex

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I am for the first time using a template for a thesis. I have the following bibliography file:

```
@article{Schwizer2017,
Author = {Schwizer, F. and Okamoto, Y. and Heinisch, T. and Gu, Y. and Pellizzoni, M. M. and Lebrun, V. and Reuter, R. and Kohler, V. and Lewis, J. C. and Ward, T. R.},
Title = {Artificial Metalloenzymes: Reaction Scope and Optimization Strategies},
Journal = {Chem Rev},
Abstract = {Abstract too long to show},
Year = {2017} }
```

In my main text file I call my bibliogrpahy:

```latex
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Biblio}
```

However when I use `\citep[][]{Schwizer2017}`, I get the error:

```
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Schwizer2017"
```

How do I solve this? I looked at a few solutions and they brought me to the point where I don't get a full encyclopedia of errors, but this one still remains.

Additional information:

I use the package "natbib" and I convert my EndNote files to .bib files, so I fear that EndNote might have something to do with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to compile using a (pdf)LaTeX > BibTeX > (pdf)LaTeX (> (pdf)LaTeX) sequence in order to use `.bib` files. Are you doing this?

Comment: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/37907)